# Most efficient way to update specific columns in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Whats the most efficient way to update a specific column in numpy?  For simplicity, say i have:

```
[[0 2]
 [1 2]
 [2 2]]
```

Then I would like to add 2 on every element on the second column.

```
[[0 4]
 [1 4]
 [2 4]]
```

This can be simply done with a loop, but I was wondering if theres a numpy function I could use that would be more efficient.  Assuming the array is quite large.

Comment: Try this: `a[:, 1] += 2` You may want to read about [Numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Arithmetic (and much much more) operations are vectorized in `numpy`, so just use `arr[:,1] += 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference a column using:

```
a = np.array([[0 2]
              [1 2]
              [2 2]]

a[:,1] += 2
```